How deploy and Run Camunda Operate dockerized behind an nginx
trying to deploy the Camunda Application on AWS ECS fargate using Nginx server but not able to deploy. How to deploy the dockerized versions camunda operate, zeebe broker, and elasticsearch on AWS ECS Fragate, required help would be appreciated!
